# Unable to click on a button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<button type="button" class="btn rd-button btn-ng-bs-animated clearfix" ng-disabled="false" ng-click="submitApplication(); $event.preventDefault();" is-submitting="isAppSubmitting" options="optionsSubmitBtn">
    <div class="icons pull-left">
        <span class="show"></span>
        <span class="show"></span>
        <span class="show"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="text ">submit your application</div>
</button>
```

I want to click on the button with text as **submit your application** from the following url :

```
https://www.randstadusa.com/jobs/search/apply/4/620370/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the button is hidden

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl07_ctl03_ApplyFormDiv > application > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(7) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > button > div.text").click()
```

this code works

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use the CSS Selectors or XPaths that Chrome generates for you. They are direct paths and if something changes on the page, it will fall over.

Comment: `ctl07_ctl03` as in `ctl07_ctl03_ApplyFormDiv` appears to be dynamic. You need to be extra careful,

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared to to click on the button with text as **submit your application** you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- `css_selector` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.rd-button.btn-ng-bs-animated.clearfix[options='optionsSubmitBtn'] div.text").click()
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn rd-button btn-ng-bs-animated clearfix' and @options='optionsSubmitBtn']//div[@class='text']").click()
  ```

Comment: as per html your answer is correct but as per url i given its not working

Comment: This selector is not specific enough. There are two elements that correspond with that XPath but only the second is clickable

Comment: You could simplify it more. Remove the class and leave: `//button[@options='optionsSubmitBtn']`. Pretty sure if OP is using Selenium, that should be enough and all OP needs is to add `.click()`

Comment: Notice that there are two elements on the page that have the class `btn rd-button   btn-ng-bs-animated clearfix`. The first has text that says `send your resume` and the second has text that says `submit your application`. We want the second one here so we need to specify a little more.

Comment: You _want the second one_ hence you need **@options='optionsSubmitBtn'**

Comment: Correct although the previous answers didn't have that. Also, not sure if it works in Selenium. It wasn't locating correctly in the DOM

Comment: so lastly the answer please

Comment: @bhupathituraga Of-coarse this is the working Answer

Comment: which one please specify

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-hide = 'openApply']//button[@class = 'btn rd-button   btn-ng-bs-animated clearfix']//div[@class = 'text ']").click()
```

Added additional constraint at the beginning because there are two buttons with the same class but one is clickable

Edit:
Added the `By` method. I like it since you can use `find_elements` with any type of attribute/selector rather than remembering each individual method.

Comment: driver.get not have attribute to click

Comment: **driver.get("//div[@ng-hide = 'openApply']")** ?

Comment: @DebanjanB fixed.

Comment: Nopes, bug still evident ;)

Comment: There we go lol. It's still early where I am!